# ASP.NET MVC4 SQL DB How does DBContext know which table to use?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext

Just started using ASP.NET MVC 4.  Tried this tutorial, i was able to work through it fine:http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4

My question is after i set up my own connection to an existing database in webconfig.  I got it reading my data etc, but HOW does DbContext know which table to use?  What specifies the table?  For instance, suppose i have two tables "Cats" and "Dogs", each the same but with different data (same fields etc though).  What is actually telling my controller and model to use the "Cats" table?  What if i simply wanted to switch it to "Dogs"?  Thanks!

Controller:

```
public class MyCatsController : Controller
{
    private MyCatDBContext db = new MyCatDBContext();

    //
    // GET: /MyCats/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.MyCats.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /MyCats/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        MyCat mycat = db.MyCats.Find(id);
        if (mycat == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(mycat);
    }

    //
    // GET: /MyCats/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /MyCats/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(MyCat mycat)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.MyCats.Add(mycat);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(mycat);
    }

    //
    // GET: /MyCats/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        MyCat mycat = db.MyCats.Find(id);
        if (mycat == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(mycat);
    }

    //
    // POST: /MyCats/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(MyCat mycat)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(mycat).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(mycat);
    }

    //
    // GET: /MyCats/Delete/5

    public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
    {
        MyCat mycat = db.MyCats.Find(id);
        if (mycat == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(mycat);
    }

    //
    // POST: /MyCats/Delete/5

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        MyCat mycat = db.MyCats.Find(id);
        db.MyCats.Remove(mycat);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class MyCat
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CatName { get; set; }


    public bool IsAlive { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string NickName { get; set; }

    public string OtherName { get { return "Mr. " + NickName; } }
}

public class MyCatDBContext : DbContext
{
    public MyCatDBContext()
        : base("MyCatDBContext")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<MyCat> MyCats { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: convention over configuration, usually based off the `Type` name

Comment: Do you mean how does this code know what table to use? `context.Cats.Add(...)`

Comment: I added the controller and model classes to my question.  Where in the code does it specify to use [dbo].[MyCats] ?  or How does it resolve this?

Comment: There is also a table [dbo].[Dogs].  It has exactly the same table definition (yes CatName for a dog haha).  How would I switch to use that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public MyCatDBContext()
        : base("MyCatDBContext")
    {
    }
```

MyCatDBContext is the connection string here.

```
public DbSet<MyCat> MyCats { get; set; }
```

Tells there is a MyCat of MyCat(Class) type table in database.
You might argue the property name is MyCats why the table name is MyCat that's a convention used by EF known as Singularized EntityType names and Pluralized EntitySet names.

```
public class MyCat
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CatName { get; set; }


    public bool IsAlive { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string NickName { get; set; }

    public string OtherName { get { return "Mr. " + NickName; } }
}
```

Class dictates the column name and datatype of each column in the table.

if you write.

```
context.MyCats.Add();
```

it adds into MyCats table

Let me know if it did't helped.

Comment: I guess what you are trying to say is that the table is determined by the Model's class name?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying about context.MyCats.Add();.  Where is this supposed to go?  I don't have any object 'context' in the code I supplied.  Are you saying 'context' instead of 'db'; as in private MyCatDBContext db=new MyCatDBContext();

Comment: then its db.MyCats.Add(). Usually i give it a name context.  you are right.

Comment: Yes table is determined by the Model(or any class) if it is added in the class drived from DbContext that is MyCatDBContext in your case.